# what should I use instead of 'appcontent' on firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have to fix our legacy firefox extension codes into WebExtensions, and I found those code on that.

```js
var appcontent = document.getElementById("appcontent");
if (appcontent) {
    appcontent.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", myfunction, 
true);
}
```

Debbuging on this, appcontent always be `null` and There is no `'appcontent'` Element on our solution.
I googled about `'appcontent'` , then I found those description.

> Extensions that attempt to overlay onto the "appcontent" box try to float chrome over document content will no longer display that material. You should update your extension to use the new panel XUL element. If you wish to keep the panel from automatically disappearing after a delay, you can set the noautohide attribute to true.

So I replaced `'appcontent'` into `'panel'` but it doesn't work, then what should I use instead of `'appcontent'` ?

Comment: You can't just change the name of the variable. You need to adjust how the extension displays content. In addition that description is talking about how extensions for FF _used_ to be made. Since mid-November FF will only accept extensions that conform to a [restricted/standardised API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions). You will not be able to use XUL. You should read the documentation.

Comment: @Andy If I don't miss Understanging English, I don't want to change the name of the variable, but I just think `appcontent` is the Reserved name like `var`, `string` or anything because our legacy code is working without any define for `appcontent` in our project(So I think `appcontent` is exist without defining).
And if it's true, there is another name that can use instead of `appcontent` and that makes our project work(that isn't working currently, that say "appcontent is null").

Comment: @Andy and, I understand that this talking about how extensions for FF used to be made.
so I want to migration that, but unfortunately I have not found any document explains about it.
example, [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Add-ons/Code_snippets/On_page_load) says that 'this document are talking about legacy technology so Don't use these and Use WebExtensions instead', but I have not found any document that JUST talking about THIS issues.

I expect that there is a page JUST talk about my problem, but I'll read the page that you put, again, carefully.